# how to find information inside the zip file in alfresco-4.2.2 version

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We are using alfresco-4.2.2 version.we are uploading the zip files.Let's say we have uploaded test.zip. I want to know the zip file information like how many files inside the zip file.when i search forms its saying the files will be stored in C:\Alfresco\alf_data\contentstore path and stored in .bin format and couldn't find the zip file that have uploaded.Is there any way to find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly not familiar with alfresco development, so I think the first thing for you to do is to check [Jeff Potts' Tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series). Once you got familiar with [Content Models](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html), [custom Behaviours](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html) and [custom Actions](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html), You can do the following :

- Design your custom model (type or aspect) in order to include the extra meta information you which (ex. file size, number of included files, compression ratio, ....)
- Either develop a Rule Action to extract those meta data from the file and set it to its properties (you will need then to setup that rule on each and every folder you want ....)
- Or simply do the trick with custom behaviors `onAddAspect` for instance, if the aspect is `my:zipfile`!